# Is it possible to integrate B2C AD with Azure SQL server

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

Is it possible to integrate Azure B2C with Azure SQL server for Authentication and Authorizations? Does Azure SQL server also supports B2C or the AD support is for ON-PREMISE supported AD only?

Comment: Absolutely, you can use Azure Active Directory Authentication for authentication with Azure SQL Database , **Not Azure AD B2C**. I don't understand why you want to use B2C with your Azure SQL database.For any one can access it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely, you can use Azure Active Directory Authentication for authentication with your Azure SQL Database , **Not Azure AD B2C**.

Azure AD B2C is a cloud identity management solution for your web and mobile applications. So, it doesn't support Azure SQL database.

Additional,If you want to use Azure AD or authentication with your Azure SQL Database, you can refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-aad-authentication).

Comment: Hi, @Manoj Kumar . If this answer is helpful to you, please mark it as answer so that we can help more people. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a specific reason why this is not supported? Custom attributes does not cut it. You need a complex queries on behalf of the customer. When you really design a truly serverless architecture, you can have the decision made at the endpoint rather going through a service when SQL server can provide the authentication and authorization (role based) capabilities.

Comment: @ManojKumar . I think you can try to use Azure AD.  Azure AD B2C is designed for web and mobile applications. According to your requirement. Azure AD is a better and only one choice. Sorry,one feature can't do anything you want to do.

Comment: With Azure AD, you are restricted to a particular domain. That is the whole premise of moving to B2C where we can use their social accounts as the identity.

Comment: @ManojKumar  You're right. This is caused by The Azure SQL server. Not Azure AD and Azure AD B2C. I understand what you want now.  It's really important.  Azure SQL server only support one admin that with the directory domain . I suggest  you  post this idea in this 
 Feedback forum:https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server   I will upvote it.

Comment: Thanks @WayneYang. I will request via feedback.

Comment: @ManojKumar . I upvoted your idea. Also , if you can post more reason on it and the Team will be more clearer for your request.  If this answer is helpful to you , please accept it as answer so that we can help more people. Thanks!:-)